# Hydra: disable permutation of few hyperparameters

Tags: python, hyperparameters, fb-hydra, omegaconf

I am trying to do a basic hyperparameter tuning. By default [Hydra](https://hydra.cc/) creates a permutation of each hyperparameter.

```
hydra:
    mode: MULTIRUN
    sweeper:
        params:
          +n: 5,10,15
          +a_lower: 0.5, 0.7, 0.9
```

Here it will run the same python file 3*3=9 times with all the permutations of `n` and `a_lower`.

In my case, some hyperparameters  are related to other. For example:

```
hydra:
    mode: MULTIRUN
    sweeper:
        params:
          +n: 5,10,15
          +a_lower: 0.5, 0.7, 0.9
          +a_upper: 1.1, 1.15
          +a: 0.91, 1.05, 1.09
          +pde_coeff: 0.1, 1.0
```

`[a_lower, a_upper, a]` should stay together, not permutate. This should not be allowed: `[a_lower, a_upper, a] = [0.5, 1.15, 1.05]`.

I tried using a list or a dictionary but the error is always the same. For example, I used this dictionary to prevent the permutations of `[a_lower, a_upper, a]`:

```
+matrix:['case 1':[0.5, 1.1, 1.05],'case 2':[0.7, 1.15, 1.09], 'case 3':[0.9, 1.15, 1.0]]
```

The error is

```
[s.1915438@sl1(sunbird) 6. inverse + logger]$ python 1.single_notebook.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 213, in run_and_report
    return func()
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydra/_internal/utils.py", line 453, in <lambda>
    lambda: hydra.run(
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydra/_internal/hydra.py", line 105, in run
    cfg = self.compose_config(
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydra/_internal/hydra.py", line 594, in compose_config
    cfg = self.config_loader.load_configuration(
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydra/_internal/config_loader_impl.py", line 141, in load_configuration
    return self._load_configuration_impl(
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydra/_internal/config_loader_impl.py", line 235, in _load_configuration_impl
    self._process_config_searchpath(config_name, parsed_overrides, caching_repo)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydra/_internal/config_loader_impl.py", line 158, in _process_config_searchpath
    loaded = repo.load_config(config_path=config_name)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydra/_internal/config_repository.py", line 349, in load_config
    ret = self.delegate.load_config(config_path=config_path)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydra/_internal/config_repository.py", line 92, in load_config
    ret = source.load_config(config_path=config_path)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hydra/_internal/core_plugins/file_config_source.py", line 31, in load_config
    cfg = OmegaConf.load(f)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/omegaconf/omegaconf.py", line 190, in load
    obj = yaml.load(file_, Loader=get_yaml_loader())
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 81, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 49, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 127, in compose_mapping_node
    while not self.check_event(MappingEndEvent):
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 428, in parse_block_mapping_key
    if self.check_token(KeyToken):
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 173, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_stream_end()
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 377, in fetch_stream_end
    self.remove_possible_simple_key()
  File "/scratch/s.1915438/env/modulus/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 318, in remove_possible_simple_key
    raise ScannerError("while scanning a simple key", key.mark,
yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in "/scratch/s.1915438/2. inverse+forward/6. inverse + logger/saved_data/conf.yaml", line 21, column 11
could not find expected ':'
  in "/scratch/s.1915438/2. inverse+forward/6. inverse + logger/saved_data/conf.yaml", line 21, column 45
[s.1915438@sl1(sunbird) 6. inverse + logger]$
```

Comment: I think you messed with the order. It should be `[a_lower, a_upper, a]` not `[a, a_lower, a_upper]`?

Comment: yes, sorry this has been modified.

Comment: Not a solution but would do the work. Use a single string for each case and just convert the string to number using a simple algo. The string should look like this: `+matrix: "0.5, 1.1, 1.05", "0.7, 1.15, 1.09","0.9, 1.15, 1.0" `

Comment: Yes this should do the trick. But I have to convert the string to numbers by removing the comma. There must be a way to implement this.

Comment: See this related Hydra feature request: https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1258